# Bluetooth low energy not working with a BTLE device

Tags: xcode, macos, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to use my mac (MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014) to connect to a device for an application I am trying to write however when setting up my CBCentralManager I am always returned with The platform doesn't support Bluetooth Low Energy.  If i check my system information under bluetooth it clearly says that My computer does support Bluetooth low energy by this statement (Bluetooth Low Energy Supported:  Yes).

What am I missing here is this me messing something up or is this something seriously wrong with my computer?

Also what can I do to bypass this annoying only Low Energy Devices and just start scanning for peripherals, seems kinda silly that it wont let me set a property to skip Low Energy.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Core Bluetooth is only for low energy devices. If you want to scan for legacy devices you need to look at the iobluetooth framework. Just to confirm this is a Mac app that you are running, not an iOS app on the simulator? https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/Bluetooth/BT_Bluetooth_On_MOSX/BT_Bluetooth_On_MOSX.html

Comment: yes a app for my mac its not for IOS.  However the error I believe is saying that my computer does not have BTLE because all I do to get the error is setup my CBCentralManager and then get the updatestate delegate call and all it says device does not support BTLE.

Comment: If possible is there any good documentation on how to use it with IOBluetooth all I can find is that it just jumps straight into the methods to use it with BTLE.

Comment: Have you restarted your Mac? Done a PRAM reset etc?

Comment: @Paulw11 so It looks like I was not all the knowledgeable in what I am trying to do,  I was trying to connect two bluetooth host devices together which seems to not be possible.  Do you know of any USB Bluetooth receivers (peripheral) devices Dongles.  That would make it so I could make a bluetooth connection from my computer to my xbox one per say?  Also the PRAM reset fixed my issue so if you could submit it as an answer I will accept it.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: You should be able to make a connection between the two devices, but it will depend on whether the devices implement a compatible set of services.  For example a headset implements the handsfree service and a Mac can connect to a handsfree service.  I am not sure what Bluetooth services an Xbox would offer.  I imagine it would support HID (keyboards) but not sure whether it would offer anything that a Mac could connect to.

Comment: Well what I want to do is connect My mac to it through bluetooth by a USB dongle in a controller slot so I can make an application where my computer acts as a xbox controller, So i can use my mouse and keyboard have an app looking for keyboard and then pass the xbox controller commands to the USB dongle via Bluetooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the Bluetooth hardware can get messed up. Try a reboot and if that doesn't work a PRAM reset.